# LearnPress version 4.x, how to remove a hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am developing a theme and that's why need to remove these two hooks. How to remove them?

```
add_action(
    'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item',
    LP()->template( 'course' )->text( '<div class="course-wrap-thumbnail">', 'course-wrap-thumbnail-open' ),
    1
);
add_action(
    'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item',
    LP()->template( 'course' )->callback( 'loop/course/badge-featured' ),
    5
);
```

Comment: where are you adding this code? Removing hooks (not adding), refer to docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/

Comment: Thanks for the refer link. I have tired to remove the hook using this code. I have added the code in my theme's functions.php file.
<code>remove_action('learn-press/before-courses-loop-item', 'loop/course/badge-featured', 5);</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a certain period of time I have checked the LearnPress plugin's core files and found the solution in commented code.

````
    'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item',
    LP()->template( 'course' )->text( '<div class="course-wrap-thumbnail">', 'course-wrap-thumbnail-open' ),
    1
);

LP()->template( 'course' )->remove( 'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item', array( '<div class="course-wrap-thumbnail">', 'course-wrap-thumbnail-open' ), 10 );

add_action(
    'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item',
    LP()->template( 'course' )->callback( 'loop/course/badge-featured' ),
    5
);

LP()->template( 'course' )->remove_callback( 'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item', 'loop/course/badge-featured', 5 );```

Each hook needs to remove by this way. It is working fine with my theme now. Thanks all of you who gave answers here.
````

Answer (score 1):

Remove actions with the remove_action hook

`remove_action( 'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item' , 'loop/course/badge-featured', 28);`

Or...

`remove_action( 'learn-press/before-courses-loop-item', LP()->template( 'course' )->callback( 'loop/course/badge-featured' ), 10 );`